# C++: Function templates

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, function

I have 2 2D arrays that represent a maze

`const char maze1[10][11]`
and
`const char maze2[20][21]`

I'm trying to create 1 function to handle both mazes like so:

```
void solveMaze(maze[][])
{
}
```

and just pass the maze like `solveMaze(maze1);`

How would I do this with function templates?

I recently asked this question already but explicitly asked not to use function templates because I wasn't sure on how to use it, but I would like to see how it would work. (hope this isn't "abusing" the system)

Comment: I don't think this could be done through templating. You would use templates if you wanted a char maze or int maze or a float maze, but not just char mazes with different dimensions.

Comment: @ChadSchouggins: actually, array dimensions can be template parameters. The canonical example is the template function to get the size of an array: `template <typename T, size_t N> size_t size(T (&)[N]) { return N; }` . The syntax is arcane though.

Comment: @codeCube: it could make sense, as template parameters are constants this could allow specific optimizations to be performed by the compiler for some sizes. It's doubtful here, but may help one day.

Comment: @codeCube: You are not entirely right. I can think of a couple of cases where you want to use an integer constant as template parameter. On example would be a templated, arbitrary-sized bitfield class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no real support for multidimensional Arrays. You should consider using a class with proper support for the dimensions. The following does the trick

```
template<int N, int M>
void solveMaze(const char (&maze)[N][M]) {
    size_t n = N;
    size_t m = M;
    int x = 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    const char maze[3][2] = { { 0, 1} , {2, 3}, {4, 5} };
    solveMaze(maze);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Very interesting. Out of curiosity, why are you passing those variables into main? are they necessary for this?

Comment: @dukevin which variables - argc and argv? These are not necessary - it is what my IDE thinks a main should look like :P

Answer (score 3):

You do not need and should not use templates to solve this problem. All you are doing is solving mazes of different sizes.

Templates are for the generation of a number of classes/functions that use various types.

Instead construct a class to store a maze. This class should store the dimentsions of the maze and give access to the components of that maze.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, it would be much simpler if you were using better arrays. The issue with C-arrays is that they have a tendency to decay to pointers easily, and once they do, the size is lost (and that, my dear, is pretty stupid as far as I am concerned...)

The choice then depends on whether you have fixed-size arrays or want dynamically-sized arrays:

- for fixed-size: `std::array` (or if unavailable `boost::array`)
- for dynamically-size: `std::vector`

Since a template will make more sense in the `std::array` case, I'll suppose that is what you elected.

```
char const maze1[10][11]
```

is equivalent to

```
std::array<std::array<char, 11>, 10> const maze1
```

It's slightly more verbose, but `std::array` proposes regular member methods like `.size()`, `.begin()`, `.end()`, etc... and it can be passed in functions easily.

Now, on to your template functions. The signature will simply be:

```
template <size_t M, size_t N>
void solveMaze(std::array<std::array<char, N>, M> const& maze);
```

However, despite your question, you more likely want not to use templates here (they are of little benefits). So I would advise using `vector` and a regular functions:

```
void solveMaze(std::vector< std::vector<char> > const& maze);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
template<int w, int h>
void solveMaze(const char (&maze)[w][h])
{
    //can use w,h now
}
```